# SQLAlchemy add a subquery as OR clause

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a sub query:

```
sub_query = db.query(Table1.id).filter(Table1.id.in_(db.query(Table2.ref_col).filter(Table2.col1 == 'value')))
```

and base query is

```
query = db.query(Table1).filter(Table1.col1 == 'value1' | Table1.col2 == 'value2')
```

Now I want to append the sub query as part of OR clause so that the sql output is

```
SELECT * From Table1 where Table1.col1 = 'value1' or Table1.col2 = 'value2' or Table1.id in (select Table2.ref_id from Table2 where Table2.col1 = 'value')
```

What is the correct method to add subquery as a OR clause in query.

PS: I cannot initialize the query using sub query. I need to add the subquery in where clause using ORM.

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: It depends on what result you expect. A [mcve] would make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

## Legacy API Example

Probably use the `.subquery()` method.

```py
Table1.col1 == 'value1' | Table1.col2 == 'value2' | Table1.id.in_(sub_query.subquery())
```

[sqlalchemy.orm.Query.subquery](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.subquery)

## Latest/Greatest API Example

Psuedo code using `select()`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

sub_query = select(Table2.ref_id).where(Table2.col1 == 'value')
query = select(Table1).where(Table1.col1 == 'value1' | Table1.col2 == 'value2' | Table1.id.in_(sub_query.subquery()))
Table1s = db.scalars(query).all()
```

Comment: Is there a way to add sub_query after the query has already been initialized. Something like

query = query.filter(Table1.id.in_(sub_query.subquery()))

The SQL statement for the above one is:

SELECT * From Table1 where Table1.col1 = 'value1' or Table1.col2 = 'value2' AND Table1.id in (select Table2.ref_id from Table2 where Table2.col1 = 'value')

I cannot initialize query with the sub_query. In the above process I somehow need to append subquery to query using OR clause